# How can I get the innerHTML of an anchor tag using Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

I want to parse some data from an HTML page. A simplified example follows.

When I run the following code I expect it to return `[ "foo", "baz", "quux", ]` but instead it throws "TypeError: anchorNode.html is not a function".

###### Fails

```
const HTML = `
  <a href="foobar">foo</a>
  <a href="bar">baz</a>
  <a href="qux">quux</a>
`;
const $ = Cheerio.load( HTML, );
const result = [];
const $a = $( 'a' );
$a.each(( i, anchorNode, ) => {
  const innerHtml = anchorNode.html();
  result.push( innerHtml, );
});
return result;
```

It's interesting to note that the following code works as expected.

###### Succeeds

```
const HTML = `
  <a href="foobar">foo</a>
  <a href="bar">baz</a>
  <a href="qux">quux</a>
`;
const $ = Cheerio.load( HTML, );
const result = [];
const $a = $( 'a' );
$a.each(( i, link, ) => result.push( link.attribs.href ));
return result;
// result: ["foobar","bar","qux"]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the first function to behave as expected?

Comment: It should be `$(anchorNode).html()`. `anchorNode` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688297/how-can-i-get-the-innerhtml-of-an-anchor-tag-using-cheerio/68688359#comment121389951_68688297) by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) -

> It should be `$(anchorNode).html()`. `anchorNode` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

anchorNode is viewed as a DOM element. This means that the native functions are only of the type https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp. You can fix this by wrapping anchorNode in $().
I.E
$(anchorNode).html()